# How to disable PreferenceFragment transparency?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I guess it's ok to set background color in some average fragment with average layout, but here I've got `PreferenceFragment`, which layout (`PreferenceScreen`) doesn't support `android:background` field. What's a neat way to handle it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following to PreferenceFragment class declaration

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
 if (view != null) {
     view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_dark));
 }

 return view;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding my answer since I had a similar issue with PreferenceFragmentCompat that wasn't quite resolved by just adding a color to the background, and this was a top result while googling the problem.

I had the same issue where using PreferenceFragmentCompat would work, but the settings background was transparent and you could still see views in the underlying activty - changing .add() to .replace() in the getSupportFragmentManger yielded the same overlay.

The solution of changing the background color worked. However, for my build the getColor() method was deprecated. I instead use the following code.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

This solved the transparency issue except for one button, which was still clickable. For the sake of brevity, the issue was I was trying to replace the layout that contained the activity views.

What ended up working was creating an empty layout at the highest order and using .replace() on that layout. The buttons are now covered and no longer clickable.

XML where button was still visible above preferences fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <!--I was replacing this layout that had all the activity views-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="Z"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/earth_acc_z"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/earth_acc_y"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/earth_acc_y"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/earth_acc_y"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"/>
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toggleRecording"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toggleRecording" 
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML of working example with new empty constraint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--FrameLayout with two nested ConstraintLayouts-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

        <!--ConstraintLayout with acitivty views-->
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

            <TextView
                android:text="Z"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/earth_acc_z"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/earth_acc_y"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/earth_acc_y"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/earth_acc_y"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toggleRecording"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toggleRecording" 
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <!--Preference fragment should replace this empty layout-->
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/preferenceFragment"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```